# Fetching 2 diffrent rows of a table with 2 foreign tables in single query?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have the main table WORDS

This table has all the word names stored in database.

Now I have a foreign table WORD_TYPES

This table stores the type of word related to main table WORDS.

Finally I have foreign table POPULAR_WORDS.

My problem is I am trying to get 2 word names from main WORDS table connected with its those 2 foreign tables WORD_TYPES & POPULAR_WORDS.

```
   SELECT 
   WORDS.word_name as word1,  
   WORDS.word_name as word2, 
   from table WORDS, WORD_TYPES, POPULAR_WORDS
   where WORDS.w_id = WORD_TYPES.w_id
   and WORDS.w_id = POPULAR_WORDS.wi_id
   ORDER BY WORDS.word_name
```

But this is not possible for me, I have tried everything. Because after I  selected a word_name from main table WORDS related to WORD_TYPES, I am not able to select the second word related to POPULAR_WORDS table.

I guess we can select only one row from a query in this specified way.

Comment: Showing us some sample data would greatly help your question.  It isn't even clear to me why you need to do all these joins.

Comment: As you are not selecting anything from WORD_TYPES or POPULAR_WORDS or limiting anything that is shown the query you show makes very little sense

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 20 years!!!

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is :

```
SELECT 
   w1.word_name as word1,  
   w2.word_name as word2, 
   FROM table WORDS w1, WORDS w2
   JOIN WORD_TYPES wt ON wt.w_id = w1.w_id
   JOIN POPULAR_WORDS pw ON pw.w_id = w2.w_id
```

Even though the final result you want to obtain is not very clear